min_samples_leaf in GradientBoostedClassifier() having weird behavior
Trying to tune the min_samples_leaf in a GradientBoostedClassifer(). I'm seeing expected results with the bias/variance tradeoff. However, just to test the boundaries, I made the min_samples_leaf > n_samples in the training dataset, expecting an error or something, but I am still getting results similar to when the model is tuned:
df = df_a # number of samples = 347
df=df.sample(frac=1) 
train_proportion = 0.8 
n = len(df)
t = int(train_proportion * n)

# separate training and test sets
y = df['detected']
X = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['detected'])]

# samples in training set
train_x = X.iloc[:t,:].reset_index().iloc[:,1:]
# samples in test set
test_x = X.iloc[t:,:].reset_index().iloc[:,1:]
#targets in train set
train_y = pd.Series(y[:t].reset_index().iloc[:,1:].iloc[:,0])
#targets in test set
test_y = pd.Series(y[t:].reset_index().iloc[:,1:].iloc[:,0])

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 10, random_state= 0, min_samples_leaf=500)
clf.fit(train_x,train_y)
print(clf.score(train_x,train_y))
print(clf.score(test_x,test_y))

output:
0.924187725631769
0.9142857142857143

Why would this be the case? I expected there would be an error or no splits would be made. There seems to be nothing in the documentation on what would happen if min_samples_leaf > n_samples. The only requirement for int's is the range [1,inf]. There's no additional notes on this, either.
I was thinking that maybe it would reset the min_samples_leaf to some usable value, but the subtrees all have no depth and no splits are made: subtree


I expected [...] no splits would be made.
[...]
the subtrees all have no depth and no splits are made

So you've already confirmed one of your suspicions. Is the only issue left for you why score looks so good? That's probably because score is the accuracy metric, and if your dataset is imbalanced and always predicting the majority class, then the accuracy is the majority's prevalence. (See stats.SE's opinion of accuracy.)

yeah, seems it's just a super imbalanced dataset...thanks
